How can I adjust the Next.js configuration file based on environment variables?
I developed a Next.js app and set up a GitLab pipeline to build and deploy it to staging and production environments. I’m using a Docker environment file for runtime variables, which works well. Recently, however, I needed to add an images.remotePatterns configuration in next.config.js. The challenge is that the remotePatterns differ between staging and production, and I’d like to adjust them based on the environment without rebuilding for each one, as this config is set at build time. Is there a way to achieve this?
On my localhost, I used loadEnvConfig to load environment variables from the .env.local file, and in next.config.js, I set remotePatterns using process.env.VAR, which works well. I could push my .env.* files to GitLab and use the same approach there. However, the problem is that once the Docker image is built, I can’t modify the Next.js configuration. I’d like to build the image once and deploy it across multiple environments without rebuilding each time.
I’ve already seen this question, but it doesn’t address my issue. As far as I understand, it’s about runtime environment variables, which I’ve already set successfully for each environment using next-runtime-env package. I built a single Docker image and used it for both staging and production, with different runtime variables. My question is specifically about changing the next.config.js file for these two environments. This configuration file is read at build time, not at runtime, and I want to avoid building the image twice.
In fact, I’m not referring to runtime variables used in the application but specifically to changing the Next.js configuration at runtime, in any way possible.

This question is similar to: How to set environment variables in react application on start of the server?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Avi I clarified the difference in my question.
